# Getting error in cvtColor

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi, raspistill

Can't find a solution for this error

File "/home/pi/glen/python/vid.py", line 8, in 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GBGR)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'COLOR_BGR2GBGR'

Comment: Please edit the code properly by selecting the code and pressing `Ctrl+K`, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for more info. Also please post your code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your desired output is grayscale of the frame.
Try this.

gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)